# how to read digits from text file and save it in an array "using MATLAB or JAVA"?

Tags: java, matlab

I have similar problem with little changes, which is:

I have text file contain large number of lines with different sizes "i.e. not all lines has same length" 
each line contain integers only.

as an example A.txt =

```
4 6 4 1 2 2 5 7 7 

0 9 5 5 3 2 43 3 32 9 0 1 3 1

3 4 5 6 7 4  

34 5 8 9 0 7 6 2 4 5 6 6 7 5 4 3 2 21 4 9 8 4 2 1 5
```

I want to put these integers into an array so each integer will be an element in the array and saving lines from "overlapping" i.e. I need to keep each line as it is.

Could anybodyy help me with this?

Comment: We're not going to do your entire homework assignment for us.  Show us what you've done and what you've tried, and how it didn't work.

Comment: it's huge program that I try to do.
it's related with my Master degree project.
but this single point i had delayed on it !!!
could you help with it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = dlmread('a.txt')
```

a =

Columns 1 through 21

```
 4     6     4     1     2     2     5     7     7     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     9     5     5     3     2    43     3    32     9     0     1     3     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3     4     5     6     7     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
34     5     8     9     0     7     6     2     4     5     6     6     7     5     4     3     2    21     4     9     8
```

Columns 22 through 25

```
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 4     2     1     5
```

Comment: greaaaaaat !!!!!!
this single command solve my problem !!!
many many thanks dude !!!!!!!!

Comment: Sami,  Please use the "accept answer" feature if this is the answer you liked best.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1) Create a new Array for each line

2) Read lines, one at a time from file

3) Split each line by the "space" char

4) Iterate through the String[] that you get from the split operation, passing each value to Integer.parseInt(value);

5) Store value in array;

6) When reading next line, create new array to store the new lines values.

Comment: thanks for your interested 
fine, but 6) needs adjustment, that is I need the whole file in one array
so could you give me how to do ??

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data using [`Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), one line at a time, and store the numbers in a [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), e.g. an [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Numbers
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    Scanner data = new Scanner(new File("A.txt"));
    List<List<Integer>> ints = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    while (data.hasNextLine()) {
      List<Integer> lineInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      Scanner lineData = new Scanner(data.nextLine());

      while (lineData.hasNextInt()) {
        lineInts.add(lineData.nextInt());
      }

      ints.add(lineInts);
    }

    System.out.println(ints);
  }
}
```

This code opens the file for reading, and creates a two-dimensional `ArrayList`. The outer list contains a list for each line in the file. The inner lists contain the integers on the respective lines. Note that empty lines result in empty lists. Also, you will have to properly handle any IO exception, unlike the code shown above.

If you really want the integers in a two dimensional array instead of an `ArrayList`, then you'll either have to call [`toArray`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()), or alter the code above. That is left as an exercise for the reader.